# How to partially reorder the stack of each bar in stacked bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stackedbarseries

Some of my data contain NA values and I want these values to appear at the top of each bar.

```
library("phyloseq"); packageVersion("phyloseq")
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
data("GlobalPatterns")
TopNOTUs <- names(sort(taxa_sums(GlobalPatterns), TRUE)[1:40])
gp.ch   <- prune_species(TopNOTUs, GlobalPatterns)


mdf = psmelt(gp.ch)
mdf$group <- paste0(mdf$Phylum, "-", mdf$Genus, sep = "")

mdf <- as.data.frame(mdf)
mdf$Genus <- as.character(mdf$Genus)
mdf[is.na(mdf)] <- 0

# Plot resultss
ggplot(mdf, aes(Phylum)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = group), colour = "grey", position = "stack")
```

Right now the NA elements appear in the middle of each bar because the stacks are organized alphabetically, how can I get the NA elements to be the top elements on each stack?

Comment: Where do you get the `GlobalPatterns` dataset from?  `phyloseq`?

Comment: yes I forgot to include that

Comment: that package has [installation issues with R 3+](https://joey711.github.io/phyloseq/install.html).  can you provide example data that doesn't rely on that package?  Or, even better, just provide example data in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `NA` to a string representation, and then reorder the factor before plotting.
There are a few ways to do this, here's a tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

levs <- levels(data$model)

# see below for where the data comes from
data %>%
  mutate(model = fct_explicit_na(model, "NA"),
         model = factor(model, levels = c("NA", levs))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(make)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = model), position = "stack")
```

[image]

For data I used a stripped down version of `mtcars`:

```
# using a stripped-down version of mtcars
data <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car_type") %>%
  filter(stringr::str_detect(car_type, "Merc|Mazda|Toyota")) %>%
  separate(car_type, c("make", "model"), extra = "drop") %>%
  mutate(model = factor(model, levels = c("RX4", "230", "Corolla")))

data
     make   model  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1   Mazda     RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2   Mazda     RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3    Merc    <NA> 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
4    Merc     230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
5    Merc    <NA> 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
6    Merc    <NA> 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
7    Merc    <NA> 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
8    Merc    <NA> 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
9    Merc    <NA> 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
10 Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
11 Toyota    <NA> 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep NA at the top when there is an unknown number of elements in the bar?

Comment: Yes, you can refer to the existing `levels()` when reordering.  See updated answer.

Comment: Does this answer resolve your question?  If so, please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.